# Spacy returns "AttributeError: 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc' object has no attribute 'spans'" in simple .spans assignment. Why?

Tags: nlp, spacy, spacy-3

I'm just trying to mark subparts of a document as spans as per [Spacy's documentation](https://spacy.io/api/doc#spans)

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
sentence = "The car with the white wheels was being confiscated by the police when the owner returns from robbing a bank"
doc = nlp(sentence)

doc.spans['remove_parts'] = [doc[2:6], doc[9:12]]
doc.spans['remove_parts']
```

This looks pretty straight forward, but Spacy returns the following error (and attributes it to the second line i.e. the assignment):

```
AttributeError: 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc' object has no attribute 'spans'
```

I can't see what's going on at all. Is this a Spacy bug? Has `spans` property been removed even though it is still in the documentation? If not what am I missing?

PD: I'm using Colab for this. And `spacy.info` shows:

```
spaCy version    2.2.4                         
Location         /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/spacy
Platform         Linux-4.19.112+-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
Python version   3.7.10                        
Models           en
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
nlp = English()
text = "The car with the white wheels was being confiscated by the police when the owner returns from robbing a bank"
doc = nlp(text)
doc.spans['remove_parts'] = [doc[2:6], doc[9:12]]
doc.spans['remove_parts']
```

should work correctly **from spaCy v3.0 onwards**. If it doesn't - can you verify that you are in fact running the code from the correct virtual environment within colab (and not a different environment using spaCy v2)? We have previously seen issues where Colab would still be accessing older installations of spaCy on the system, instead of sourcing the code from the correct venv. To double check, you can try running the code in a Python console directly instead of through Colab.

Comment: OH, no, no, no, sorry... the doc has been created before. I just skipped that part as I assumed it.  Notice that the error talks about a 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc' object, which indicates that it is indeed a Doc object.  

Regarding the installation, Colab already includes Spacy, no need to install it, and it has been working for me with everything including displacy, textacy and other libraries on top.  It doesn't matter if it was 2.x as the `spans` property was already included. Unless I'm still missing sth. I'll add the import and doc creation just in case though. Thanks!

Comment: I'm seeing Colab uses vers. 2.2.4. I can't install PyCharm here now... I hope I can do it soon. Yet it should work in vers 2 too...

Comment: `doc.spans` is definitely only available since spaCy 3.0, so the version conflict with Colab will be the culprit here. (you might be confusing with `doc.ents`, which has been around for much longer)

Comment: Oah... Yes... that definitely makes sense. I was deluded by the fact that Spacy's documentation marks new features with a v3.0 tag, and `spans` it isn't marked as such, but it must be an oblivion. Yet... if you see https://spacy.io/api/doc#init , `ents` is actually marked as a 3.0 feature... which makes me not being totally confident, but you probably meant `sents`?

Comment: If you're certaing that 'spans' is a 3.0-only feature, can you add that to your answer (or do you agree that I add it) instead of the paragraphs about the 'Doc' issue (which could deviate people from the real problem -sorry for not making that explicit at the beginning) so that I can mark it as the real answer?

Comment: I've clarified my answer, but I'm not going to change it entirely because you keep changing the question ;-) Your original question was specifically about v3.0, and my answer stated specifically that my cited code should work for v3.

Comment: Hi, I didn’t ask to change it entirely… And I don’t get why’d making the change I asked you for, or any, depend on me having changed the question. Of course I’ve changed it; 1 of the things I think it makes SO having good quality content, is that you can improve questions and answers for the others and oneself to understand it better. If my original, or any, version of my question said it was about 3.0, then 1st, it was wrong, cause I realised Colab hadn’t still updated Spacy to v3. And 2nd, your answer wouldn’t be as useful for others, cause you say it works  in 3.0, while I say it doesn’t.

Comment: That makes people doubt. But a Q&A like ‘Why this doesn’t work?’ “It is cos you’re not using v3,”, is more clear/straightforward -no doubts evoked. Also, in this case, it would reflect reality. Changing is good, at least if made to clarify things. If you see what I asked you to change anyway, it wasn’t this; it was  actually about removing the other part about creating docs. I already explained in my first comment that that could not be the case for the error reported in my questio, so  it could distract from the real (problem)/ solution of (not/) using Spacy 3.0, which I wanted to highlight.

Comment: Anyway, it is your answer and I wanted to respect it; that’s why I didn’t change it myself. And, as I’m saying, the part that helped me did help me a lot and I’m of course accepting it as the answer. So thanks a lot for the help!